# Why TCP FIN/ACK packets have payload data but length is 0?

Tags: linux, http, tcp, tcpdump

I use tcpdump to capture some data, but found that the `FIN` and `ACK` packets have some payload while the length is 0.  Can anyone explain that?  When I use Wireshark to see the pcap file, all is right.  Why is that?

```
20:56:05.174314 IP 10.0.2.15.20281 > 192.168.4.80.21224: Flags [.], ack 1721, win 33232, length 0
    0x0000:  0004 0001 0006 0800 2793 4e00 0000 0800  ........'.N.....
    0x0010:  4500 0028 417a 4000 4006 284f 0a00 020f  E..(Az@.@.(O....
    0x0020:  c0a8 0450 4f39 52e8 b35c bf82 f4d8 b0ba  ...PO9R..\......
    0x0030:  5010 81d0 d121 0000 4745 5420 2f75 7365  P....!..GET./use
    0x0040:  7273 2f31 3f75 7365                      rs/1?use
20:56:15.179096 IP 10.0.2.15.20281 > 192.168.4.80.21224: Flags [F.], seq 649, ack 1721, win 33232, length 0
    0x0000:  0004 0001 0006 0800 2793 4e00 0000 0800  ........'.N.....
    0x0010:  4500 0028 417b 4000 4006 284e 0a00 020f  E..(A{@.@.(N....
    0x0020:  c0a8 0450 4f39 52e8 b35c bf82 f4d8 b0ba  ...PO9R..\......
    0x0030:  5011 81d0 d121 0000 0000 0000 0000 2e31  P....!.........1
    0x0040:  2035 3030 2049 6e74                      .500.Int
20:56:15.179528 IP 192.168.4.80.21224 > 10.0.2.15.20281: Flags [.], ack 650, win 65535, length 0
    0x0000:  0000 0001 0006 5254 0012 3502 0000 0800  ......RT..5.....
    0x0010:  4500 0028 73f3 0000 4006 35d6 c0a8 0450  E..(s...@.5....P
    0x0020:  0a00 020f 52e8 4f39 f4d8 b0ba b35c bf83  ....R.O9.....\..
    0x0030:  5010 ffff 2438 0000 0000 0000 0000 2e31  P...$8.........1
    0x0040:  2035 3030 2049 6e74 6572 6e61 6c20       .500.Internal.
20:56:15.181826 IP 192.168.4.80.21224 > 10.0.2.15.20281: Flags [F.], seq 1721, ack 650, win 65535, length 0
    0x0000:  0000 0001 0006 5254 0012 3502 0000 0800  ......RT..5.....
    0x0010:  4500 0028 73f5 0000 4006 35d4 c0a8 0450  E..(s...@.5....P
    0x0020:  0a00 020f 52e8 4f39 f4d8 b0ba b35c bf83  ....R.O9.....\..
    0x0030:  5011 ffff 2437 0000 0000 0000 0000 7365  P...$7........se
    0x0040:  7273 2f31 3f75 7365 725f 6964 3d35       rs/1?user_id=5
20:56:15.181884 IP 10.0.2.15.20281 > 192.168.4.80.21224: Flags [.], ack 1722, win 33232, length 0
    0x0000:  0004 0001 0006 0800 2793 4e00 0000 0800  ........'.N.....
    0x0010:  4500 0028 eaf7 4000 4006 7ed1 0a00 020f  E..(..@.@.~.....
    0x0020:  c0a8 0450 4f39 52e8 b35c bf83 f4d8 b0bb  ...PO9R..\......
    0x0030:  5010 81d0 a266 0000 4745 5420 2f75 7365  P....f..GET./use
    0x0040:  7273 2f31 3f75 7365                      rs/1?use
```

Comment: If Wireshark shows proper lengths, then it is likely a bug in tcpdump

Comment: It seems like this is HTTP. Could it be that tcpdump does not consider HTTP requests/answers to be data?